# DatabaseError: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\x96'

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.7.20. My schema, tables and columns are all supporting `utf8mb4`. I used the following:

```
ALTER SCHEMA `MyDB`  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci ;
ALTER TABLE MyDB.Videos CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

I don't understand why I'm still getting the following error:

```
DatabaseError: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\x96' for column 'Content' at row 1
```

I can't figure out the reason, please help.

Comment: Use proper `SET NAMES` on the client side.

Comment: Thanks, I only had to specify CHARSET='UTF8MB4' in my connection parameters.

Comment: Specifying on the connection (where practical) is preferred over `SET NAMES`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I specified CHARSET='UTF8MB4'in my connection parameters, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Set is working

```
cursor.execute("SET NAMES 'UTF8MB4'")
cursor.execute("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8MB4")
```